# How to Insert SVG into React Link

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to replace the ❌ icon with "/xmark-solid.svg", but obviously failed on the "Close" line. Also want to do similar with question mark and settings icons.

```
<div className="top-right">
    {page !== "game" ? (
      link("/xmark-solid.svg", "Close", "game")
    ) : (
      <>
        {link("❓", "About", "about")}
        {link("⚙️", "Settings", "settings")}
      </>
    )}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly using svg , export the svg in a separate js file and import it and use it

```js
export const closeIcon = ()=> your svg here 

//import and use it in your component

link(closeIcon, "Close", "game")
```

Comment: Thank you Jakeer for the reply. I am not sure I follow you. Where do I specify the separate js file?

Comment: I tried this but it did not work: export const closeIcon = ()=> "./xmark-solid.svg";